# Bash script: 'Syntax error: "fi" unexpected' within nested statement

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, scripting, syntax-error

I am trying to write a script to toggle HAproxy to reroute a user to a maintenance page if a service is down. Here is the part I am having trouble with:

```
if [ "$idIsValid" = "false" ]; then
    if [ "$(cat isUp)" = "true" ]; then
            echo "Site is down! Routing to maintenance page."
            echo false > isUp
            mv haproxy.cfg haproxy.cfg.temp
            mv haproxy.cfg.other haproxy.cfg
            mv haproxy.cfg.temp haproxy.cfg.other

            #restart haproxy
            service haproxy restart
            echo "Restarting HAproxy"

    elif [ "$(cat isUp)" = "false" ]; then
            #do nothing since it has already changed
            echo "Nothing to do; service is still down."
    else
            #notify me that isUp is set to something other than true or false, or something else is wrong.
    fi
fi
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
status-check.sh: Syntax error: "fi" unexpected
```

This error is pointing to the **nested fi** on that second to last line. I am having trouble finding the syntax error here. Please assist! Thank you.

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ would have told you the reason, by the way.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks for the link! I'll be using it from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there are no commands in the last `else` block. If you either remove this block or put a command in there (not a comment) you won't get a syntax error.

Comment: It's always something silly...Thank you very much for your help!